# mounting a data partition

Tags: partition, root

I have installed Debian 9 in a laptop and created a partition for data.  the partition is mounted as /dev/sda7 and I can see it in the file directory as /data/

But the owner is root and I cannot save any file or create any folder.  I tried changing permissions with chmod (even as sudo) it does not work.

Any help on how to gain access to this partition?

Thanks a lot

Comment: just some info. Partition type W95 FAT32

Comment: Please elaborate on ‘‘I tried changing permissions with chmod (even as sudo) it does not work.’’

Comment: I tried this command  sudo chmod u=rwx,g=rwx,o=rwx /data/ 
and the ownership remains as root.

Comment: Well, naturally; `chmod` changes the mode.  If you don’t use `chown`, the owner isn’t going to change. Did the mode change to 777 (`drwxrwxrwx`)?  Is there a non-alphabetic character after the third `rwx`?  And, with `/data` protected 777, are non-root users still unable to create files in it?

Comment: thanks. changing the owner with chown solved the problem. thanks again

Answer (score 0):

First determine that Linux is aware of the device.

lsblk

should contain your device. Take note of the device name, size and mount point.

If the RO (read only) column is one the file system is read only and you'll always be denied permission.

If the file system is read write and has a mount point type

mount | grep /dev/sdX

and determine if the mount options specify default permissions. If they do then you need to change those options.

If the mount point was created from an automount like udev or systemd then you need to check those configurations. I'm assuming you're mounting your drive under your user using mount here.